# 3d model visualization settings

Tags: 3d-view

[image: 3d view]
I am modeling a house in solid view. I have some problems with the visualization. Expecially where non complanar faces have the same colours, this is confusing and pretty much annoying since it is quite difficult to have a real vision of the solid that appears flattened and with no depth.
Are there some particular settings that I should modify?

Comment: Have you explored the Viewport Shading Options for Solid View yet? (Down chevron on the right of the VP Shading icons) Some of them have higher directional contrast than this.. and you can create your own

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cavity wity Type:World.
[image]

Comment: Using "Random" Color or changing "Material" color per object/surface also helps

Comment: I had tried that already, but the edges are too "fuzzy".

Answer (score 1):

Activate the wireframe option in the Overlays in the geometry section > wireframe. You find it in the upper part of the screen near the shade modes.